# Can't vote to close as off-topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

I can't vote to close [this question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/can-android-apps-detect-emf).

[image]

Not sure why the Vote to Close button is greyed out, it is not greyed out for other options. It also clearly states I have 24 votes remaining.

Comment: Note, question provided is an example. I can't vote to close off-topic on any site I have the close privilege.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem; Chrome 15 on Windows 7. Select a "close on" site, and "Vote To Close" is enabled. Select "is off topic" again, and "Vote To Close" stays enabled, and I'm able to close the question.

Comment: Same problem as a diamond on SU - FF8/Win7.

Comment: As workaround: first select another option, then go back to "is off topic", then "Vote to close" is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed next deploy; a subtle glitch crept in that was *intended* to help when selecting duplicate questions, but had a side-effect